# Read specific date range from csv file using Python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I've got a csv file with over 60 million records in it in the format,

```
2013-07-23 17:04:34, some data, some more data
```

I want to write a Python script that allows a user to put in a "To" and a "From" date in the format "2013-04-23" and "2013-04-25". I then want to search for all records within that range and display them.

I'm using Python 2.7 on a windows 7 machine (developing using Eclipse) but when complete, this script will run on a Linux Red Hat server.

So, a scaled down version of what I have is:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from_date = raw_input('\nEnter FROM Date (e.g. 2013-11-29) :')
    from_date += ' 00:00:00'
    print('From date: = ' + from_date)
    to_date = raw_input('\nEnter TO Date (e.g. 2013-11-30) :')
    to_date += ' 23:59:59'

    in_file = './file.csv'
    for line in in_file:
        fields = line.split(',')
        found_from_date = re.match(from_date, fields[0])
        if found_from_date:
            found_to_date = re.match(to_date, fields[0])
            if found_to_date:
                print(line)

    in_file.close()
```

As you can see I'm currently use regex but that of course means that I only pick up exact matches. I can of course write some code that splits up each date field and matches each individual field but I was hoping that there's some date range function I can use.

I did a bit of Googleing and came across something called [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/index.html), but before downloading and learning I just wanted to make sure there isn't something more standard / easier and that can be updated using the Red Hat package manager.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [datetime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module is your friend here, seeing as how it has built in capabilities to compare dates. I can't recall if there's a method that takes in a preformatted string and converts it to a `datetime.date`, but it's simple enough to parse that bit out:

```
import datetime

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from_raw = raw_input('\nEnter FROM Date (e.g. 2013-11-29) :')
    from_date = datetime.date(*map(int, from_raw.split('-')))
    print 'From date: = ' + str(from_date)
    to_raw = raw_input('\nEnter TO Date (e.g. 2013-11-30) :')
    to_date = datetime.date(*map(int, to_raw.split('-')))

    in_file = './file.csv'
    for line in in_file:
        fields = line.split(',')
        found_date = datetime.date(*map(int, fields[0].split(' ')[0].split('-')))
        if from_date <= found_date <= to_date:
            print line

    in_file.close()
```

Comment: Thanks Mostly Harmless. Got it to work using your suggestions but for found_date I did this: `file_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(fields[0], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" )`. The only downside is that it runs slow - takes 22 min to process 65 000 000 records, but it works. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Bruce I took a look at `strptime`, and at least on my system it looks like it runs somewhere around 5-6 times slower than `datetime.date` - admittedly you lose the time, but based on your sample code I don't think that's important. I updated my answer to parse around the time part of the timestamp (didn't notice it the first time around), I'd be interested to see if it helps at all.

Comment: you're a champion. Speed went up drastically - the same amount of records finished in 4 mins 32 seconds. Problem solved!

Comment: Happy to be of assistance ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at dateutil.
http://labix.org/python-dateutil
Perhaps the rrule.between(after, before, inc=False) is what you're after?